# Garbage value in Some/None without return statement

Tags: scala, return

Why does the following code (fibonacci series) behave differently if I do not use 'return' statement. I thought that we do not need 'return'.

```
def nthFibonacci(nth:Int): Option[Int] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def go(previousNo:Int, nextNo:Int, currentCount:Int, nth:Int):Option[Int]= {
    if (currentCount == nth) Some(previousNo)
    else go(nextNo,previousNo+nextNo,currentCount+1,nth)
  }

  if (nth<=0) None //invalid argument check
  if (nth==1) Some(0) //first fibonacci
  if (nth == 2) Some(1) //second fibonacci
  go(1,(0+1),2,nth)
}
```

//for n=0,1 I get garbage while I should get None or Some.

nthFibonacci (0)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1070270178)

nthFibonacci(1)
res1: Option[Int] = Some(-2140540357)

nthFibonacci(2)
res2: Option[Int] = Some(1)

Interestingly, if I change the code and add 'return', the code works!
      if (nth<=0) return None //invalid argument check
      if (nth==1) return Some(0) //first fibonacci
      if (nth == 2) return Some(1) //second fibonacci
      go(1,(0+1),2,nth)

```
nthFibonacci (0)
res0: Option[Int] = None

nthFibonacci(1)
res1: Option[Int] = Some(0)

nthFibonacci(2)
res2: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

Another observation is that if I use if/else then the code seem to work fine without return. But I cannot understand why I am forced to write either return or if/else

```
if (nth<=0) None
  else if (nth == 1) Some(0)
  else if (nth == 2)  Some(1)
  else go(1,(0+1),2,nth)

nthFibonacci (0) //None
nthFibonacci(1) //Some(0)
nthFibonacci(2) //Some(1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's the way control flow works in Scala. Since `go` is your last expression, your `if-else` expression simply returns a value which is being ignored.

Pattern matching can help here:

```
nth match {
  case 0 => None
  case 1 => Some(0)
  case 2 => Some(1)
  case _ => go(1, (0 + 1), 2, nth)
}
```

This is an alternative to the `if-else` expression. If you still want to go with `if-else`, make sure to include an `else` in your last branch.